# p4 filelog with regex

Tags: python, regex, perforce

Can anyone please give an example for p4 filelog with regex.I need to get the date of first revisions of the file from p4 filelog command and thus use the regular expression for getting date.

for instance the command: p4 logfile filename#1

will return something like:

//depot/prod/../../filename
… #1 change 123345 move/add on 2018/05/23 by user@user
… … moved from //depot/prod/../../../

i want to use regex to get the date.

Comment: Please include some data in your question.

Comment: does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex to do this.

```
% p4 filelog foo#1
//stream/main/foo
... #1 change 93 add on 2018/04/01 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'foo'
... ... branch into //stream/main/boo#1


% p4 -F %date% filelog foo#1
2018/04/01
```

Comment: This gives series of dates, but i only want the first date it was mofidied on...any suggestions for that?

Comment: Ah, your file was moved -- you can use the `-1` flag to specify that you only want the history of the given filename.  If you want the earliest revision across different filenames, just get all the revisions and `tail -n1`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import re

log = '//depot/prod/../../filename … #1 change 123345 move/add on 2018/05/23 by user@user… … moved from //depot/prod/../../../'
print(re.search(r' on (\S+)', log).group(1))
```

Output

```
2018/05/23
```